# issue encountered using Backend Estimator using providers from qiskit_braket_providers

Tags: quantum-computing, chemistry, qiskit

I am carrying out a ground state estimation of a molecule via qiskit-nature workflows. As explained in  [qiskit documentation](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/nature/tutorials/03_ground_state_solvers.html) I define a [VQE solver](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.minimum_eigensolvers.VQE.html)   by means of a [backend estimator](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.primitives.BackendEstimator.html) that runs on a specific backend. Normally I use different backends (mainly the IBMQ backends, the local Aer backends and other remote simulators available for the scientific community), this time I would like to address the backends included in the [qiskit_braket_provider](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-braket-provider) module for the sake of comparison among different qubit modalities.

Once I defined the problem as in the above mentioned qiskit documentation, I carry out the usual workflow that worked in other backends.

```
        from qiskit_braket_provider import AWSBraketProvider
        provider = AWSBraketProvider()
        from qiskit_nature.second_q.algorithms import GroundStateEigensolver
        from qiskit_nature.second_q.mappers import JordanWignerMapper
        from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SPSA
        from qiskit.algorithms.minimum_eigensolvers import VQE
        from qiskit_nature.second_q.circuit.library import UCCSD, HartreeFock
        from qiskit.primitives import BackendEstimator as BEstimator
        my_optimizer=SPSA(maxiter=30)
        mybackend = provider.get_backend("SV1")
        my_est=BEstimator(backend=mybackend)
        mapper=JordanWignerMapper()
        
        ansatz = UCCSD(
            problem.num_spatial_orbitals,
            problem.num_particles,
            mapper,
            initial_state=HartreeFock(
                problem.num_spatial_orbitals,
                problem.num_particles,
                mapper,
                ),
            )
        
        vqe_solver = VQE(my_est, ansatz, my_optimizer)
        vqe_solver.initial_point=np.zeros(ansatz.num_parameters)
        calc = GroundStateEigensolver(mapper, vqe_solver)
        res = calc.solve(problem)
```

This time I got the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File [...]/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/minimum_eigensolvers/vqe.py:254, in VQE._get_evaluate_energy.<locals>.evaluate_energy(parameters)
    253     job = self.estimator.run(batch_size * [ansatz], batch_size * [operator], parameters)
--> 254     estimator_result = job.result()
    255 except Exception as exc:

File [...]/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/primitives/primitive_job.py:55, in PrimitiveJob.result(self)
     54 self._check_submitted()
---> 55 return self._future.result()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py:446, in Future.result(self, timeout)
    445 elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 446     return self.__get_result()
    447 else:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py:391, in Future.__get_result(self)
    390 try:
--> 391     raise self._exception
    392 finally:
    393     # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py:58, in _WorkItem.run(self)
     57 try:
---> 58     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
     59 except BaseException as exc:

File [...]/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/primitives/backend_estimator.py:255, in BackendEstimator._call(self, circuits, observables, parameter_values, **run_options)
    254 # Run
--> 255 result, metadata = _run_circuits(bound_circuits, self._backend, **run_options)
    257 return self._postprocessing(result, accum, metadata)

File [...]/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/primitives/backend_estimator.py:72, in _run_circuits(circuits, backend, **run_options)
     71 else:
---> 72     result = [backend.run(circuits, **run_options).result()]
     73 return result, metadata

File [...]/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit_braket_provider/providers/braket_backend.py:247, in AWSBraketBackend.run(self, run_input, **options)
    245     raise QiskitBraketException(f"Unsupported input type: {type(run_input)}")
--> 247 braket_circuits = list(convert_qiskit_to_braket_circuits(circuits))
    249 if options.pop("verbatim", False):

File ~/.qbraid/environments/qiskit_i5o7if/pyenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit_braket_provider/providers/adapter.py:412, in convert_qiskit_to_braket_circuits(circuits)
    411 for circuit in circuits:
--> 412     yield convert_qiskit_to_braket_circuit(circuit)

File [...]/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit_braket_provider/providers/adapter.py:371, in convert_qiskit_to_braket_circuit(circuit)
    366 if name == "measure":
    367     # TODO: change Probability result type for Sample for proper functioning # pylint:disable=fixme
    368     # Getting the index from the bit mapping
    369     quantum_circuit.add_result_type(
    370         # pylint:disable=fixme
--> 371         result_types.Sample(
    372             observable=observables.Z(),
    373             target=[
    374                 circuit.find_bit(qiskit_gates[1][0]).index,
    375                 circuit.find_bit(qiskit_gates[2][0]).index,
    376             ],
    377         )
    378     )
    379 elif name == "barrier":
    380     # This does not exist

File [...]/python3.9/site-packages/braket/circuits/result_types.py:547, in Sample.__init__(self, observable, target)
    530 """
    531 Args:
    532     observable (Observable): the observable for the result type
   (...)
    545     >>> ResultType.Sample(observable=tensor_product, target=[0, 1])
    546 """
--> 547 super().__init__(
    548     ascii_symbols=[f"Sample({obs_ascii})" for obs_ascii in observable.ascii_symbols],
    549     observable=observable,
    550     target=target,
    551 )

File [...]/python3.9/site-packages/braket/circuits/result_type.py:231, in ObservableResultType.__init__(self, ascii_symbols, observable, target)
    230 elif self._observable.qubit_count != len(self._target):
--> 231     raise ValueError(
    232         f"Observable's qubit count {self._observable.qubit_count} and "
    233         f"the size of the target qubit set {self._target} must be equal"
    234     )
    235 elif self._observable.qubit_count != len(self.ascii_symbols):

ValueError: Observable's qubit count 1 and the size of the target qubit set QubitSet([Qubit(4), Qubit(3)]) must be equal

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

AlgorithmError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 64
     62 vqe_solver.initial_point=np.zeros(ansatz.num_parameters)
     63 calc = GroundStateEigensolver(mapper, vqe_solver)
---> 64 res = calc.solve(problem)
     65 print(res)
     66 t.write(str(res))

File [...]/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit_nature/second_q/algorithms/ground_state_solvers/ground_state_eigensolver.py:96, in GroundStateEigensolver.solve(self, problem, aux_operators)
     85 """Compute Ground State properties.
     86 
     87 Args:
   (...)
     93     :meth:`~.BaseProblem.interpret`.
     94 """
     95 main_operator, aux_ops = self.get_qubit_operators(problem, aux_operators)
---> 96 raw_mes_result = self.solver.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(  # type: ignore
     97     main_operator, aux_ops
     98 )
    100 eigenstate_result = EigenstateResult.from_result(raw_mes_result)
    101 result = problem.interpret(eigenstate_result)

File [...]/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/minimum_eigensolvers/vqe.py:191, in VQE.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(self, operator, aux_operators)
    186 else:
    187     # we always want to submit as many estimations per job as possible for minimal
    188     # overhead on the hardware
    189     was_updated = _set_default_batchsize(self.optimizer)
--> 191     optimizer_result = self.optimizer.minimize(
    192         fun=evaluate_energy, x0=initial_point, jac=evaluate_gradient, bounds=bounds
    193     )
    195     # reset to original value
    196     if was_updated:

File [...]/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/optimizers/spsa.py:514, in SPSA.minimize(self, fun, x0, jac, bounds)
    504 def minimize(
    505     self,
    506     fun: Callable[[POINT], float],
   (...)
    511     # ensure learning rate and perturbation are correctly set: either none or both
    512     # this happens only here because for the calibration the loss function is required
    513     if self.learning_rate is None and self.perturbation is None:
--> 514         get_eta, get_eps = self.calibrate(fun, x0, max_evals_grouped=self._max_evals_grouped)
    515     else:
    516         get_eta, get_eps = _validate_pert_and_learningrate(
    517             self.perturbation, self.learning_rate
    518         )

File [...]/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/optimizers/spsa.py:335, in SPSA.calibrate(loss, initial_point, c, stability_constant, target_magnitude, alpha, gamma, modelspace, max_evals_grouped)
    332     pert = bernoulli_perturbation(dim)
    333     points += [initial_point + c * pert, initial_point - c * pert]
--> 335 losses = _batch_evaluate(loss, points, max_evals_grouped)
    337 avg_magnitudes = 0.0
    338 for i in range(steps):

File [...]/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/optimizers/spsa.py:748, in _batch_evaluate(function, points, max_evals_grouped, unpack_points)
    746         results += _as_list(function(*batch))
    747     else:
--> 748         results += _as_list(function(batch))
    750 return results

File [...]/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/minimum_eigensolvers/vqe.py:256, in VQE._get_evaluate_energy.<locals>.evaluate_energy(parameters)
    254     estimator_result = job.result()
    255 except Exception as exc:
--> 256     raise AlgorithmError("The primitive job to evaluate the energy failed!") from exc
    258 values = estimator_result.values
    260 if self.callback is not None:

AlgorithmError: 'The primitive job to evaluate the energy failed!'
```

I tried to upgrade the packages of the qiskit sdk (now I am using [qiskit 0.44.0](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.44/index.html) . I tried to use different optimizers, the error message changes a little but I don't succeed in running a proper vqe workflow. I am using python 3.9.
Do I need to specify any methods in the BackendEstimator call or to encapsulate the backend in a different way to make it work?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran it and it seems that your problem is with the specified provider/backend. The problem got solved when I used "ibmq_qasm_simulator" as the backend. If you just want the problem solved.

Just use this instead:

```
IBMProvider()
provider = IBMProvider(instance="your_instance")
mybackend = provider.get_backend("ibmq_qasm_simulator")
```

and just comment out all of the AWS related code

Comment: Thank you very much  for your answer. As I mentioned in the top, I already run this code on other backends, including all free backends that can be accessed through  IBMProvider(). I'm doing this for the sake of comparison among different qubit modalities on the same code. Maybe this fact was not clear in my introductory part. I will try to edit and improve the question. Thank you.